# contact form works but method or closure "refresh" gives an error

Tags: php, yii, widget, refresh, contacts

I made a widget for a contact form by adaption the standard contactform, which works fine. The email gets send, but on the refresh i get the error:

`contact and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "refresh".`

When i refres the page the error is gone and the message "we'll get in touch with you" is displayed. I've been breaking my head and am probably looking in the wrong direction, but can't find the cause...

Model:

```
    class ContactForm extends CFormModel
{
    public $gender;
    public $name;
    public $lastname;
    public $email;
    //public $subject;
    //public $body;
    //public $verifyCode;

    /**
     * Declares the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            // name, email, subject and body are required
            array('name, lastname, email, gender', 'required'),
            // email has to be a valid email address
            array('email', 'email'),
            // verifyCode needs to be entered correctly
            //array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements()),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Declares customized attribute labels.
     * If not declared here, an attribute would have a label that is
     * the same as its name with the first letter in upper case.
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'verifyCode'=>'Verification Code',
        );
    }
}
```

Component:

```
   class contact extends CWidget
{
    public function run()
    {
        $model=new ContactForm;
        if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['ContactForm'];
            if($model->validate())
            {
                $name='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($model->name).'?=';
                $subject='Contact Kumbia Website '.$model->name.' '.$model->lastname;
                $headers="From: $name $lastname <{$model->email}>\r\n".
                    "Reply-To: {$model->email}\r\n".
                    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
                    "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
                $body='Deze persoon wil graag contact met ons!! ('.$model->gender.') Email: '.$model->email.' Abrazo Team Website...';

                mail(Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'],$subject,$body,$headers);
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('contact','Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
                $this->refresh();
            }
        }
        $this->render('_contact',array('model'=>$model));
    }
}
```

Component view:

```
    <div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'contact-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
)); ?>

    <div class="lijn"></div>
    <?php //echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                <?php
                    echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'gender',
                        array(  'Mannetje' => 'MALE',
                                'Vrouwtje' => 'FEMALE' ),
                        array( 'separator' => " &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " ) );
                ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'gender'); ?>
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                FIRST NAME
            </td>
            <td style="width:100px;">
                <?php //echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                LAST NAME
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php //echo $form->labelEx($model,'lastname'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'lastname'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'lastname'); ?>
            </td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                EMAIL ADDRESS
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php //echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        <tr>
    </table>

    <div class="lijn2"></div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Main.php

```
<?php $this->widget('application.components.contact'); ?>
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means, that you are trying to call non-existend method from any yii component.

You have `$this->refresh();` in your `contact` widget. I guess you wanted `$model->refresh()`, but this is method only from `CActiveRecord`, but not from `CFormModel`. Simply remove line with `$this->refresh();` and it should be fine.

Comment: I guess he wanted to [refresh a page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#refresh-detail) meaning the method of [controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWidget#getController-detail). In this case `$this->controller->refresh()` must be called.

Comment: Nice! Tried removing $this->refresh(); before, but then the page doesn't refresh ;-) You're right, I had to call the method of the controller. Thanks!